# Try-catch in Vimscript

Tags: exception, vim

I am trying to catch an error (E490) in Vim like this:

```
:try | foldopen! | catch | | endtry
```

Still, when executing this, Vim shows the error:

```
Error detected while processing :
E490: No fold found
```

I would like to open all folds if any are present.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a bug: your version shows an error,

```
:execute 'try | foldopen! | catch | | endtry'
```

acts like

```
:echo 'try | foldopen! | catch | | endtry'
```

without folds.

Try the following workaround:

```
:execute "try\n    foldopen!\ncatch\nendtry'
```

By the way, there is a better way if you want to ignore all errors:

```
:silent! foldopen!
```

Note that it won't purge messages from redirection if it is present, while `try...catch` will.

Comment: How would this look like when invoking vim with --remote-silent? `vim --remote-tab-silent "+${1};execute 'try\nfoldopen!\ncatch\nendtry'" "${2}"` causes `E481 No range allowed`. $1 is a line number $2 is a file name.

Comment: @Nickolay Kolev: `\n` works only in double-quoted strings. Don't change them to single-quoted, it is not python.

Comment: It seems the problem is not in the quotes: `"+${1};execute \"try\nfoldopen!\ncatch\nendtry\""` behaves identically.

Comment: @Nickolay Kolev: I missed this: you are using `+{cmd}` to specify command that should be executed when file opens, but you separate commands using `;`, while you should use `|`.

Comment: Or you can move this to `:execute`: `"+execute \"+$1\ntry\nfoldopen!\ncatch\nendtry\""`.

Comment: Solved using `"+${1}|silent! foldopen!"`. Thanks for the help!